# Liquefying of Nitrogen & Oxygen Gaseous to Liquid Phase. Thermodynamics. How to plot solution? Solved

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, equation-solving, data

**Process of Liquefying of air composed of 79% Nitrogen & 21% Oxygen from Gaseous to Liquid Phases as Follows:**

**1) When Temperature is higher than T>83 k they both are gas.**

**2) at T=83 k and less slightly the phase transformation take place to right O2 and to Left N2. as expected N2 Liquefy faster than O2, Where mixture are presents of both substances.**

**3)Finally at T=73 k both Substances are liquid with slight percentage of O2 gas.**

**Solved!**
**How do i plot last part of the code my solution on same plot.**

**Here's the question to calcify things**

[image]

**Here is my full code!**

```
t1[x_] := 77.4 + 25.27*x - 33.66*x^2 + 51.52*x^3 - 42.65*x^4 + 12.32*x^5; 

t2[x_] := 77.4 + 8.372*x - 6.162*x^2 + 14.62*x^3 + 2.201*x^4 - 6.235*x^5; 


    p1 = Plot[{t1[x], t2[x]}, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {76, 92}}, 
   PlotLegends -> "Expressions", ImageSize -> Large]

no = 40*0.21; 
nn = 40*0.79; 

x1 = FindRoot[t1[x] == 78, {x, 1}]
x2 = FindRoot[t2[x] == 83, {x, 1}]
xg = x /. x1
xl = x /. x2


sol = Flatten[Thread[Solve[{xg == ngo/(ngn + ngo), xl == nlo/(nln + nlo), 
       no == ngo + nlo, nn == ngn + nln}, {ngo, nlo, ngn, nln}, Reals]]] /. Rule -> Equal
```

**Plot must be similar to Figure**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have not yet received a solution to the problem. Use `xg = x /. FindRoot[t1[x] == 78, {x, 1}]; xl = x /. FindRoot[t2[x] == 83, {x, 1}];
sol = NSolve[{xg == ngo/(ngn + ngo), xl == nlo/(nln + nlo), 
   no == ngo + nlo, nn == ngn + nln}, {ngo, nlo, ngn, nln}, Reals]`

Comment: i did it please check right now.
Thanks for passing brother :)

Comment: {ngo, nlo, ngn, nln} - is it the number of moles of oxygen and nitrogen in the gas and liquid phase?

Comment: yes sir exactly

Comment: it's ok if you eliminate after solution two point of nitrogen {ngn, nln}

Comment: i got to graph them, but look like there's mistake in solution because point range x greater than one!

sol1 = Eliminate[sol, {ngn, nln}]
l1 = {sol1}
l2 = {78, 83}
p2 = ListPlot[{l1, l2}, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {76, 92}}, Joined -> {False, False}]
Show[p1, p2]

Comment: i will post solution soon

Comment: Sorry, use `pl = First[{{xl, nlo}, {xl, nln}} /. sol]` and `pg = First[{{xg, ngo}, {xg, ngn}} /. sol]`

Comment: i did this part the other way around :) 
but there's confusion in solution and point !

Comment: What are you trying to do beyond just plotting the phase boundaries?  It's not entirely clear from what you've written.  If you're trying to re-create the arrows on the figure, note that the top-left point in the dashed "parallelogram" is just `{0.21, t1[0.21]}`, and the bottom-right point is `{0.21, t2[0.21]}`.  I would recommend that you use `FindRoot` (rather than `Solve`) to find the x-coordinates of the top-right and bottom-left points.

Comment: you are right it's tricky equation. 
i post latest best answer as try i will update later

Answer (score 1):

```
t1[x_] := 77.4 + 25.27*x - 33.66*x^2 + 51.52*x^3 - 42.65*x^4 + 12.32*x^5; 
t2[x_] := 77.4 + 8.372*x - 6.162*x^2 + 14.62*x^3 + 2.201*x^4 - 6.235*x^5; 

pp1 = Plot[{t1[x], t2[x]}, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {76, 92}}, 
    PlotLegends -> "Expressions", ImageSize -> Large];


"Number of moles 21% nOxygen 79% nNitrogen"
no = 40*0.21; 
nn = 40*0.79; 



"Part Liquefying of Oxygen"


####PURE*GAS####
xg1 = x /. FindRoot[t1[x] == 83, {x, 1}]

sol1 = Flatten[Thread[Solve[{xg1 == ngo/(ngn + ngo), xl1 == (nlo/(nln + nlo))*no == 
        ngo + nlo, nn == ngn + nln}, {ngo, nlo, ngn, nln}]]] /. Rule -> Equal

g1 = Graphics[{Arrow[{{xg1, 90}, {xg1, 83}}]}]; 

p1 = Graphics[{Blue, PointSize[0.01], Point[{xg1, 83}]}];



####MIX####

xm1 = x /. FindRoot[t2[x] == 83, {x, 0.2, 0.6}]

sol2 = Flatten[Thread[Solve[{xg1 == ngo/(ngn + ngo), xl1 == (nlo/(nln + nlo))*no == 
        ngo + nlo, nn == ngn + nln}, {ngo, nlo, ngn, nln}]]] /. Rule -> Equal

g2 = Graphics[{Arrow[{{xg1, 83}, {xm1, 83}}]}];

p2 = Graphics[{Green, PointSize[0.01], Point[{xm1, 83}]}]; 



####PURE*LIQUID####

xl1 = x /. FindRoot[t2[x] == 78, {x, 0.6, 0}]

sol3 = Flatten[Thread[Solve[{xg1 == ngo/(ngn + ngo), xl1 == (nlo/(nln + nlo))*no == 
        ngo + nlo, nn == ngn + nln}, {ngo, nlo, ngn, nln}]]] /. Rule -> Equal

g3 = Graphics[{Arrow[{{xm1, 83}, {xl1, 78}}]}];

p3 = Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.01], Point[{xl1, 78}]}];




"Part Liquefying of Nitrogen"


####PURE*GAS####
xg2 = x /. FindRoot[t1[x] == 83, {x, 1}]

sol4 = Flatten[Thread[Solve[{xg2 == ngo/(ngn + ngo), xl2 == (nlo/(nln + nlo))*no == 
        ngo + nlo, nn == ngn + nln}, {ngo, nlo, ngn, nln}]]] /. Rule -> Equal

g4 = Graphics[{Arrow[{{xg2, 90}, {xg2, 83}}]}];

p4 = Graphics[{Blue, PointSize[0.01], Point[{xg2, 83}]}]; 


####MIX####

xm2 = x /. FindRoot[t1[x] == 78, {x, 0.2, 0.6}]

sol5 = Flatten[Thread[Solve[{xg2 == ngo/(ngn + ngo), xl2 == (nlo/(nln + nlo))*no == 
        ngo + nlo, nn == ngn + nln}, {ngo, nlo, ngn, nln}]]] /. Rule -> Equal

g5 = Graphics[{Arrow[{{xg2, 83}, {xm2, 78}}]}]; 

p5 = Graphics[{Green, PointSize[0.01], Point[{xm2, 78}]}];


####PURE*LIQUID####
xl2 = x /. FindRoot[t2[x] == 78, {x, 0.6, 0}]
sol6 = Flatten[Thread[Solve[{xg2 == ngo/(ngn + ngo), xl2 == (nlo/(nln + nlo))*no == 
        ngo + nlo, nn == ngn + nln}, {ngo, nlo, ngn, nln}]]] /. Rule -> Equal

g6 = Graphics[{Arrow[{{xm2, 78}, {xl2, 78}}]}]; 

p6 = Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.01], Point[{xl2, 78}]}]; 



"Graph"
    Show[{pp1, g1, g2, g3, p1, p2, p3, g4, g5, g6, p4, p5, p6}, 
      {FrameLabel -> {"X", "T(k)"}}]
```

[image]